# How do HTML DOM properties works?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is `document.InnerText` a variable?

If not then why it has assignment operator like this code below:

```js
document.InnerText=count
```

I tried to reverse the count and document part it doesnt work the other way.

Comment: well the document does not have innerText. You can create properties on objects which is what you just did. I also am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: _"I tried to reverse the count and document part"_ Not got a clue what you mean by that!

Comment: Sorry i mean countEl.innerText=count

Comment: I mean the reversevlike this this count=countEl.innerText

Comment: `count=countEl.innerText` would assign the current text content of the `countEl` element, to the variable `count`. But we still have no idea what you mean by "doesn't work." If you want to get help here on this site, then please get into the habit of providing proper [mre]s with questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this diagram](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the HTML Document Object Model. You'll see `document` is the top of the tree. It contains a root element, which is the `html`, which contains every html element in your web page.

Only the html elements can have innerText. Here is a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) of the built-in methods and properties of the document object; innerText isn't in there. But JavaScript objects are built on the fly (unlike in most object oriented languages like Java, where they must be defined in advance). Try saying `document.potato = 7`. The JavaScript interpreter will happily create a `potato` property within the document and assign the value 7 to it.

What does this do to the web page? Nothing at all, because the `potato` property means nothing to the engine in the browser that draws the page. But if later on in the program you say `console.log(document.potato)` it will print 7 in the console for you.

So when you say `document.InnerText=count` it will create the property. But like `potato` it doesn't do anything, because the browser engine doesn't recognize that property. That's why it's not doing anything.